# Sql to Linq transformation

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have these tables

posts
id, title, text,author_id, publish_date;

categories
id, category

categories_posts
id,category_id, post_id

How can i get all posts from a specific category using the id from categories table in linq.

Comment: what are the generated class names?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
var posts = dataContext.GetTable<Post>()
    .Where(p => p.CategoriesPost.Any(cp => cp.CategoryId == categoryId));
```